# jQuery onClick function to submit data to php "not defined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The following button calls a jQuery function onClick.  However, the Firefox dev console says "postData is not defined."

Here is the button and the jQuery script.

```
    <div class="center_text_grid flex-item EMail_Pwd">

    <button class="btn_joinnow" id="btn_joinnow" style="color:rgb(255,255,255)" onClick="postData()">Click to Submit Data</button></div>

function sendReply() {
    // autoresponder
}

postData().done(sendReply);

</script>

</form><br>

<br><br><br>

<!-- ________________ -->

<script type="text/javascript">

function postData() {
    return $.ajax({
    var datastring = $("#echo_test").serialize();
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "echo_test.php",
       data: {post: datastring},
    });
});
}
```

Why does the console say the function postData is not defined?

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: There are many problems with the code provided above. Correct the syntax errors so we can accurately answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand why you need two nested ajax calls, you really don't need them, I think. In any case, you can't declare a variable like this `var datastring = $("#echo_test").serialize();` inside curly brackets, so move that line outside the ajax call.

Also take into consideration the order in which you declare/execute functions.

So, moving the script, where the function is declared, up:

```
<div class="center_text_grid flex-item EMail_Pwd">
    <button class="btn_joinnow" id="btn_joinnow" style="color:rgb(255,255,255)" onClick="postData()">Click to Submit Data</button></div>


<script type="text/javascript">
function postData() {
    var datastring = $("#echo_test").serialize();
    return $.ajax({

       type: "POST",
       url: "echo_test.php",
       data: {post: datastring},
    });
}
</script>
<script>
function sendReply() {
    // autoresponder
}

//also, this line is not needed for the button to work, this is just if
//you need the function to execute on page load as well
postData().done(sendReply); 

</script>
```

HIH

Answer (score 2):

you are calling postData before to implement the method, as mentioned move your function document.ready or put

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function postData() {
        return $.ajax({
        var datastring = $("#echo_test").serialize();
        $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "echo_test.php",
           data: {post: datastring},
        });
    });
    }
</script>
```

in the head of the html file

Comment: Please correct the syntax error in your code. C-n-P the OP's incorrect code is notreally very helpful.

Comment: do you mean close the script tag or something else?

Comment: You said there are multiple syntax errors.  I am correcting the onClick now.  Anything else you see?

Comment: just edited, close the script file, move the tag before the body tag and everything should work

Answer (score 1):

Remove `onclick` from the button and add handler in the `$(document.ready)` function:

```
<button class="btn_joinnow" id="btn_joinnow" style="color:rgb(255,255,255)">Click to Submit Data</button></div>

...

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
      function postData() {
        return $.ajax({
        var datastring = $("#echo_test").serialize();
        $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "echo_test.php",
           data: {post: datastring},
        });
      });

      $("#btn_joinnow").click(postData);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Where is the document.ready function?  This page does not have one.  How would the handler know when the button is clicked if there is no onclick event?

Comment: If you are using jQuery, `document.ready` is the first function you would come across. `$(function()` is a shorthand for `$(document.ready)` The last line of my function literally attaches the click event to the button. I suggest you brush up your skills in jQuery.

Comment: Now I understand.  With your help and @GJCode's answer, I think I understand now.  Thanks.

Comment: Your answer is premature. There is nothing wrong with using the `onclick` attribute. But the OP's code has so many syntax errors that it is impossible to determine _how many_ corrections are needed. (the first being to change `onClick` to `onclick`)